# Returning null user data from Firestore. How to reference it globaly instead?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm quite new to Flutter and I've been struggling to access a user's document on Firestore.

On the profile page,
I'm setting the current user's UID inside initState, but uid returns null for a quick second, then the page updates with correct info.

So I am able to retrieve a certain field (like displayName), but it isn't quite the best practice. I don't want to have a bunch of boilerplate code and await functions mixed with UI and such.

Code:

```
FirebaseUser user;
  String error;

  void setUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    setState(() {
      this.user = user;
      this.error = null;
    });
  }

  void setError(e) {
    setState(() {
      this.user = null;
      this.error = e.toString();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(setUser).catchError(setError);
  }
```

Then in my body I have a Stream builder to get the document.

```
body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .document(user.uid)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor:
                        AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.deepOrange),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                var userDocument = snapshot.data;
                return showProfileHeader(userDocument);
              }
            },
          )
```

I want to make 'global' references to be accessed throughout the app. Instead of getting the user's id on every page and streaming a specific field when I might need multiple ones.

The only ways I found online to do something similar, created lists with all the data in it. I feel like this might get extra fields I don't need.

How can I make data from Firestore available across the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the "Provider" package for doing state management across my app. Nowadays its also the suggested way by the google flutter team when it comes to state management. See the package here: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Regarding Firebase Auth and accessing the credentials application wide, i am using that said package like stated on this page:
https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-flutter-firebase/

Short version below. Bootstrap your app like so:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        // Make user stream available
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged),

        // not needed for your problem but here you can see how
        // to define other Providers (types) for your app.
        // You need a counter class which holds your model of course.
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Counter(0)),
      ],

      // All data will be available in this child and descendents
      child: MaterialApp(...)
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your child widgets, just do:

```
// Some widget deeply nested in the widget tree...
class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      var user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

      return Text(user.displayName) // or user.uid or user.email....

  }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I like the idea of using this package, I'm reading more about it. I tested your code but displayName gets called null, can't really figure out why.

Comment: you sure you logged in successfully? user.uid should always be there after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` returns a future, and until that future is completed, you will not have the proper `FirebaseUser` object.

Making the user object global is not a bad idea. In addition, you can hook it up to the FirebaseAuth stream so that it gets updated everytime the user auth status changes, like so in a `user.dart` file:

```
class User {
  static FirebaseUser _user;

  static get user => _user;

  static void init() async {
    _user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.listen((firebaseUser) {
      _user = firebaseUser;
    });
  }
}
```

You can call `User.init()` in `main()` and access the user object with `User.user`.